# What is the size of light bulb for my ceiling fan, socket number E307185?

Tags: ceiling-fan, light-fixture

My ceiling fan has an unusual size fixture. It's larger than candelabra, but smaller than a standard medium. I suspect it might be intermediate, but I'm not quite willing to buy a converter with a huge shipping cost until I can get it confirmed. The brand is Hampton Bay. The fixture has a number E307185. Bonus points if you can find a method to convert the light bulb to a standard medium light bulb.

Comment: Call Hampton Bay's customer service to find out the socket size.  Home Depot (or Lowe's or a specialty lighting store) should have intermediate base bulbs.

Comment: [intermediate to candelabra reducers](http://lightbulbetc.com/Intermediate-to-Candelabra-Socket-Reducer/M/B000XPW4MO.htm?traffic_src=froogle&utm_medium=CSE&utm_source=froogle) can be found online for ~$3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an intermediate base.  I found them on Amazon.  [http://www.amazon.com/Watt-Light-Bulb-Intermediate-Clear/dp/B000QUXZTC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000QUXZTC)

Answer (score 0):

I purchased these, base converters and use regular bulbs. The previous link didnt work, see picture for the name.
[image: E12-E26 light adapter socket]

see link:
https://www.amazon.com/Candelabra-Adapter-Converter-Convert-Chandelier/

Comment: Your link does not work.